# Filter dataframe based on closest year in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I've a data frame for a water supply project in a residential area. I want to subset/filter my data frame. I want to keep the two pipes whose year of construction (PipeYear) is closest to the year the residential properties were built (PropertyYearBuilt) **before** the property was constructed and **after** the property was constructed.

**The condition to be satisfied**: one of **two rows** for PricePipe should be either **before** PropertyYearBuilt or **after** PropertyYearBuilt and those **two rows should be closest** to **PropertyYearBuilt** based on **PipeYear**. So literally, we retain two rows (before and after) for each PropertyYearBuilt.

My data looks like this:

```
PipeID  PricePipe   PipeYear PropertyYearBuilt  Distance_to_property
a       500         2010     2013               1.5
b       600         2007     2008               2.5
c       700         2009     2000               3.0
d       800         1998     1972               4.2
e       900         2003     1980               4.5
f       200         2014     1985               5.0
g       100         2011     1990               5.5
h       850         2018     1995               7.0
```

From a simple visual inspection, I can retain two pipes whose year of construction is closest to PropertyYearBuilt before and after. For example, **PropertyYearBuilt** 2013 is preceded by **PipeID (g)** whose PipeYear is 2011 and its succeeded by **PipeID (f)** whose PipeYear is 2014. The output I want looks like this:

```
PipeID  PricePipe   PipeYear PropertyYearBuilt  Distance_to_property
    b       600         2007     2008               2.5
    c       700         2009     2008               3.0
    d       800         1998     2000               4.2
    e       900         2003     2000               4.5
    f       200         2014     2013               5.0
    g       100         2011     2013               5.5
```

PipeYear is before and after based on PropertyYearBuilt. I dropped the **first** and **last** rows **Because their PipeYear is not closest to any PropertyYearBuilt**. This means **all PropertyYearBuilt are paired up with two PipeYear (closest before and after)**.

```
a       500         2010     2013               1.5

h       850         2018     1995               7.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `PropertyYearBuilt` data changes between your sample data and expected output. On the same note, it seems odd that `PipeID` of `"d"` is on a property that was built in two different years.

Comment: FYI, [tag:datatable] is not the same as [tag:data.table]. The Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect, please verify what it recommends (and/or what you chose) by mousing over them and ensuring they mean what you think they do. In this case, the description for [tag:datatable] explicitly says to not use it for R's `data.table` package.

Comment: I have fixed PipeIDs to avoid confusion

Comment: I also choose data.table

Comment: Your data is (still) inconsistent: for instance, `g` in your input data has `PropertyYearBuilt = 1990`, and in your expected output `PropertyYearBuilt = 2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interest, and only because I'd just found the new `dplyr` things being released ([and only currently available on GitHub](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/dplyr-1-1-0-is-coming-soon/#join-improvements)), there's some nice ways to do it with `dplyr` joins. This would require a unique `PropertyID` identifier to be added:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text="
PipeID  PricePipe   PipeYear PropertyYearBuilt  Distance_to_property
    a       500         2010     2013               1.5
    b       600         2007     2008               2.5
    c       700         2009     2008               3.0
    d       800         1998     2000               4.2
    e       900         2003     2000               4.5
    f       200         2014     2013               5.0
    g       100         2011     2013               5.5
    h       850         2018     2008               7.0", header = TRUE) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(PropertyID = as.numeric(as.factor(PropertyYearBuilt)))

bind_rows(
  df |>
    select(PropertyYearBuilt, PropertyID) |>
    unique() |>
    left_join(
      df |> select(-PropertyYearBuilt),
      join_by(PropertyID, closest(PropertyYearBuilt <= PipeYear))
    ),
  df |>
    select(PropertyYearBuilt, PropertyID) |>
    unique() |>
    left_join(
      df |> select(-PropertyYearBuilt),
      join_by(PropertyID, closest(PropertyYearBuilt >= PipeYear))
    )
  
) |>
  arrange(PipeID)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   PropertyYearBuilt PropertyID PipeID PricePipe PipeYear Distance_to_property
#>               <int>      <dbl> <chr>      <int>    <int>                <dbl>
#> 1              2008          2 b            600     2007                  2.5
#> 2              2008          2 c            700     2009                  3  
#> 3              2000          1 d            800     1998                  4.2
#> 4              2000          1 e            900     2003                  4.5
#> 5              2013          3 f            200     2014                  5  
#> 6              2013          3 g            100     2011                  5.5
```

Comment: I do think r2evans' answer is pretty neat and a lot fewer lines though!

Comment: Thanks Andy. I posted a question quite similar but different now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74819084/subset-a-data-frame-based-on-year-column-with-the-closest-value-below-and-farthe

Comment: should hopefully be a flexible solution across these two :). Make sure you mark questions answered if it's working in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do it, but I can't be sure based on inconsistencies in the sample data.

```r
quux <- read.table(text="
PipeID  PricePipe   PipeYear PropertyYearBuilt  Distance_to_property
    a       500         2010     2013               1.5
    a       600         2007     2008               2.5
    b       700         2009     2008               3.0
    b       800         1998     2000               4.2
    c       900         2003     2000               4.5
    c       200         2014     2013               5.0
    d       100         2011     2013               5.5
    d       850         2018     2008               7.0", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(PropertyYearBuilt, befaft = (PipeYear > PropertyYearBuilt)) %>%
  slice_min(abs(PipeYear - PropertyYearBuilt)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#   PipeID PricePipe PipeYear PropertyYearBuilt Distance_to_property befaft
#   <chr>      <int>    <int>             <int>                <dbl> <lgl> 
# 1 b            800     1998              2000                  4.2 FALSE 
# 2 c            900     2003              2000                  4.5 TRUE  
# 3 a            600     2007              2008                  2.5 FALSE 
# 4 b            700     2009              2008                  3   TRUE  
# 5 d            100     2011              2013                  5.5 FALSE 
# 6 c            200     2014              2013                  5   TRUE
```

Comment: I'll try this. FYI, I've updated pipe IDs to avoid confusion. Thanks!