# Subset a data frame based on year column with the closest value below and farthest value above another year column

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, data-cleaning

Subset dataframe based on **PipeYear** with the closest value below **PropertyYearBuilt** and farthest value above the **PropertyYearBuilt** using the following R code:

```
df <- read.table(text="
PipeID  PricePipe   PipeYear PropertyYearBuilt  Distance_to_property
    a       500         2010     2013               1.5
    b       600         2007     2008               2.5
    c       700         2009     2008               3.0
    d       800         1998     2000               4.2
    e       900         2003     2000               4.5
    f       200         2014     2013               5.0
    g       100         2011     2013               5.5
    h       850         2018     2008               7.0", header = TRUE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar answer to one I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74819051/10744082) (if you have latest `dplyr` updates), but this time the furthest above is just the `max` grouped by `PropertyID`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text="
PipeID  PricePipe   PipeYear PropertyYearBuilt  Distance_to_property
    a       500         2010     2013               1.5
    b       600         2007     2008               2.5
    c       700         2009     2008               3.0
    d       800         1998     2000               4.2
    e       900         2003     2000               4.5
    f       200         2014     2013               5.0
    g       100         2011     2013               5.5
    h       850         2018     2008               7.0", header = TRUE) |> 
  mutate(PropertyID = as.numeric(as.factor(PropertyYearBuilt)))

bind_rows(
  df |>
    select(PropertyYearBuilt, PropertyID) |>
    unique() |>
    left_join(
      df |> select(-PropertyYearBuilt),
      join_by(PropertyID, closest(PropertyYearBuilt >= PipeYear))
    ),
df |> 
  group_by(PropertyYearBuilt) |> 
  filter(PipeYear == max(PipeYear))
) |> 
  arrange(PropertyID, PipeYear)
#>   PropertyYearBuilt PropertyID PipeID PricePipe PipeYear Distance_to_property
#> 1              2000          1      d       800     1998                  4.2
#> 2              2000          1      e       900     2003                  4.5
#> 3              2008          2      b       600     2007                  2.5
#> 4              2008          2      h       850     2018                  7.0
#> 5              2013          3      g       100     2011                  5.5
#> 6              2013          3      f       200     2014                  5.0
```

Comment: Looks like I've troubles with the latest dplyr version. When I run pak::pak("tidyverse/dplyr") I'm getting this error: Error:                                                       
! error in pak subprocess
Caused by error: 
! Cannot install packages:
* tidyverse/dplyr: ! Bad GitHub credentials, make sure that your GitHub token is valid.
Caused by error in `stop(http_error(resp))`:
! Unauthorized (HTTP 401).

Comment: I think it needs a GitHub account and setting a PAT do download through. [Some helpful instructions here](https://usethis.r-lib.org/articles/git-credentials.html#get-a-personal-access-token-pat) for a simple approach.